# Why won't text in tkinter change?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am having a trouble changing text in python even though though that I saw a lot of use it

My code:

```
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()

def change_text():
    btn.config(text = "second text")

btn = Button(window ,text= "first text" , command= change_text).pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code is good but it is not good to make `.pack()` in the same line

```
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()

def change_text():
    btn.config(text = "second text")


btn = Button(window ,text= "first text" , command= change_text )
btn.pack()





window.mainloop()
```

it works just will

Comment: You haven't explained why it doesn't work

Answer (score 4):

You assigned the return value of `.pack()` to `btn`, and `pack` doesn't return the widget it was called on (it returns `None` implicitly, since it has no useful return value). Just split up the creation of the button from the packing:

```
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()

def change_text():
    btn.config(text="second text")


btn = Button(window, text="first text", command=change_text)
btn.pack()

window.mainloop()
```